# How to retrieve a variable value inside a text string between quotes

Tags: r, excel, r-glue

I need to export a table from R to Excel.
One of the Excel columns has to be a hyperlink. So I'm adding a new column to build a string text using the "**=HYPERLINK**" function so Excel will interpret it as a hyperlink.

Excel HYPERLINK function:

> =HYPERLINK(**link_location**, [**friendly_name**])

To construct my hyperlink, I need to use 2 variables from the original table.

1. The "**Id**" variable to build the URL for the "**link_location**"
2. The "**CaseNumber**" variable to be displayed as "**friendly_name**"

Based on my example:

> =HYPERLINK(**Id**, [**CaseNumber**])

So first I tried:

```
Import %>%
    select (Id, CaseNumber) %>%
    mutate(CaseLink = glue::glue("=HYPERLINK(https://abc.xyz/{Id}, {CaseNumber})"))
```

Output example:

| Id | CaseNumber | CaseLink |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5004V000000000000A | 00000001 | =HYPERLINK(https://abc.xyz/5004V000000000000A, 00000001) |

But it did not work because Excel requires the "**link_location**" URL to be under double quotes, like:

> =HYPERLINK("https://abc.xyz/5004V000000000000A", 00000001)

So I used the function glue::double_quote to have the "**link_location**" URL string between double quotes:

```
Import %>%
    select (Id, CaseNumber) %>%
    mutate(CaseLink = glue::glue('=HYPERLINK({glue::glue_collapse(glue::double_quote("https://abc.xyz/{Id}"))}, {CaseNumber})'))
```

But it also did not work because it is no longer retrieving the "**Id**" info, but printing it as text "*{Id}*" as part of the string!

Output example:

| Id | CaseNumber | CaseLink |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5004V000000000000A | 00000001 | =HYPERLINK("https://abc.xyz/{Id}", 00000001) |

But what I needed is:

| Id | CaseNumber | CaseLink |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5004V000000000000A | 00000001 | =HYPERLINK("https://abc.xyz/5004V000000000000A", 00000001) |

Anyone could help me to correct it to accomplish such a result? It doesn't need to be using the glue package or using the HYPERLINK function from Excel. Other options and ideas are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with `stringr::str_glue`:

```
import %>%
    mutate(CaseLink = str_glue('=HYPERLINK("https://abc.xyz/{Id}", {CaseNumber})'))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  id                 case_num CaseLink                                                  
  <chr>              <chr>    <glue>                                                    
1 5004V000000000000A 00000001 =HYPERLINK("https://abc.xyz/5004V000000000000A", 00000001)
```

Comment: Additional notes in case someone is facing the same problem to have a formula working on an exported Excel file. 
Even though the above answer solved how to build the formula, Excel was still not interpreting the column as a formula, so what I did was convert the column to "xl_formula" class using: `class(df$CaseLink) <- 'xl_formula'`.
Now when exported to Excel the cells are interpreted as formulas, and the link works. Thanks @Abigail for unblocking me and please let me know if there is a better solution.